# iOS 7.x: app would like to access your motion activity does not show up

Tags: ios7, permissions

I have an app that uses Motion activity feature. On the first run there is a pop up asking user permission to use the feature. But after re-installing the app, the pop up does not show up anymore.

Is this an intended behavior or am I missing something?

Comment: I am having a problem where it pops up but it pops up behind the app (i.e. you don't see it until you press the home button to exit the app to the iPhone home screen / springboard). Did you figure this one out?

Answer (score 0):

so it figures you need to instantiate `CMMotionActivityManager` for this to work. 
make sure you don't miss out on the first line

```
_motionActivityManager =[[CMMotionActivityManager alloc] init];
    if([CMMotionActivityManager isActivityAvailable])
        NSLog(@"available");
    else
        NSLog(@"not available");

    [_motionActivityManager startActivityUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue new] withHandler: ^(CMMotionActivity *activity) {

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            UIAlertView *theAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"activity"
                                                               message: activity.description
                                                              delegate:self
                                                     cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                     otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [theAlert show];
            if(activity.stationary)
            {
                NSLog(@"stationatry");
            }
            if(activity.walking)
            {
                NSLog(@"walking");
            }
            if(activity.automotive)
            {
                NSLog(@"automotive");
            }
            if(activity.cycling)
            {
                NSLog(@"cycling");
            }
            if(activity.unknown)
            {
                NSLog(@"unknown");
            }
        });
    }];
```